# frm.showDialog dispose when openFileDialog close [vb.net]

Tags: vb.net, forms, dispose, openfiledialog, showdialog

I have two forms. First form is used to display a set of record and second form is used to edit the particular record. I called the second form using frm.ShowDialog(). Inside that form I got a button to call the OpenFileDialog. When I press OK or Cancel, then the second form dispose together with the OpenFileDialog. I'm pretty should that my code is correct, but it was the ShowDialog() problem. Anyone have idea on this issue?

This is how i called the second form from the first form to display the Information.

```
Private Sub btnViewOrganizationEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnViewOrganizationEdit.Click, dgvOrganization.DoubleClick
    Dim selectedOrganization As New Organization
    'check permission because double click
    If dgvOrganization.RowCount > 0 Then
        strOrganizationID = dgvOrganization.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells(0).Value
        selectedOrganization = helperOrganizationCKJ.getOrganizationByID(strOrganizationID)
        frmEditOrganizationCKJ.objOrganization = selectedOrganization
        frmEditOrganizationCKJ.ShowDialog()
        iniGridView()
    End If
End Sub
```

This is how i called the OpenFileDialog.

```
Private Sub btnEditOrganizationImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEditOrganizationImage.Click
    dlgImage.Filter = ""
    Dim codecs() As ImageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
    Dim sep As String = String.Empty
    For Each c As ImageCodecInfo In codecs
        Dim codecName As String = c.CodecName.Substring(8).Replace("Codec", "Files").Trim()
        dlgImage.Filter = String.Format("{0}{1}{2} ({3})|{3}", dlgImage.Filter, sep, codecName, c.FilenameExtension)
        sep = "|"
    Next
    dlgImage.FilterIndex = 5

    If dlgImage.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
        'Get the image name
        Dim img = dlgImage.FileName
        picEditOrganizationImage.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(img)
    End If
End Sub
```

The frmEditOrganizationCKJ just dispose together with the dispose of OpenFileDialog.

Comment: I dont understand the question or problem.  A form shown as ShowDialog is not disposed when you close it, your `frmEditOrganizationCKJ` will go out of scope when it closes though.  It also looks like you really have 3 forms: the first form, `frmEditOrganizationCKJ` and `dlgImage`

Comment: @Plutonix It is actually the parent dialog is closed with child dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have copy/pasted your *btnEditOrganizationImage* from a button that has the [DialogResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) property set to something different than DialogResult.None.

This triggers the closing action for your modal form and the fix is really simple.
Set the property DialogResult for the *btnEditOrganizationImage* to `DialogResult.None`

From MSDN on Button.DialogResult

> If the DialogResult for this property is set to anything other than
>   None, and if the parent form was displayed through the ShowDialog
>   method, clicking the button closes the parent form without your having
>   to hook up any events. The form's DialogResult property is then set to
>   the DialogResult of the button when the button is clicked

Comment: Oh I see. I copy from the root form that also has a same button to call a OpenFileDialog and the DialogResult is set to Cancel.